# How to speedup PC

Tags: modeling, rendering

Before i had 8 GB RAM, I brought 16GB RAM extra. Will i cant seen difference when i have my additional 16GB RAM, Blender render took same render time, How to notice or change for my total 24GB RAM experience. Same lagging before and after adding additional RAM. Any solution to speed up my desktop PC. Thanks

Comment: If you're rendering using GPU, upgrade your graphics card. RAM doesn't really speed up render time - that's more dependent on your CPU/GPU (whichever one you're using to render).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett if i dont have GPU then? just with 24GB CPU how the render works?

Answer (score 2):

Adding more RAM will allow you to deal with more complex scenes and a higher vertex count, but it is not going to *speed up* your computer or render faster. As a matter of fact, the more complex the scene, the longer it will take to compute the render, as the CPU will need to process more data.

For shorter rendering times you need more processing units. Either  multiple CPUs or more cores, and maybe at a higher clock speed as well.

For faster rendering in GPU, then you need more GPUs, two GPUs will render the same scene in almost half the time. 4 GPUs will cut render time to 1/4.

Another way to render faster is to use a render farm, where the rendering tasks are carried out by many computers simultaneously. There are multiple render farm services online, some are free, most are not. And there are also alternatives like cloud computing like Amazon EC2 where you can use many instances simultaneously or have access to fast computers and advanced GPUs.